# Table values of non trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function using integral form

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I want to build a table values of non trivial of Riemann zeta function using the following function up to $ 10^4$ zero  ,For all $s\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$ the integral relation
$$\zeta(s) = \frac{2^{s-1}}{s-1}-2^s\!\int_0^{\infty}\!\!\!\frac{\sin(s\arctan t)}{(1+t^2)^\frac{s}{2}(\mathrm{e}^{\pi\,t}+1)}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$ , I have got a [code here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/random-matrices/zeros-of-the-riemann-zeta-function.html) but using Gaussian random distribution matrix but this really hard for me to build a table values , any help ?

Comment: Can you please show us the code you tried?

Comment: Would using the Mathematica function `Zeta` help?

Comment: Zeros of the Riemann zeta function are discussed at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeros.html, and Mathematica provides the first 10000 zeros in about two minutes on my computer by `tab = Table[Im@N@ZetaZero[n], {n, 10000}];`